# Cardviews in my app doesn't look same in different devices

Tags: android, android-cardview

Cardviews in my app doesn't look same in different devices. I have searched and made some changes but I was unable to make it look same in all devices of Android. As you can see below, I uploaded images for you to understand my problem better. Thank you in advance for any help...

My App looks like this in my device.

[App looks like that in my device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Vea.png)

[App looks like that in other device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdtAP.png)

here is the code of XML for the card view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_gray"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding0"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding0"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding10">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="@dimen/padding2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding4"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#EEEEEE"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/padding2">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding6"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            app:siBorderWidth="@dimen/padding2"
            app:siBorderColor="@color/primary_dark"
            app:shadow="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding24"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding24"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Hierarchy View (if you can reproduce the problem in an emulator) or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: I use real phone instead of emulator. I dont really undestand what you mean with Hierarchy view?